# What is the "best practice" for choosing character encoding with PHP/MySQL applications?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm self-taught php programmer, so I often don't know the "correct" way to do something. I want to normalize my character encoding practices between my PHP, HTML, and MySQL data.

-- live in the US,
-- work on sites for people who speak English,
-- most foreign languages I will encounter are western (Spanish, Italian, French)
-- living near NYC I could encounter Hebrew, Russian, etc. though I'd avoid using their character system and would only use whatever accents necessary to use Latin characters.

Anyone want to comment on which I should choose UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1? Or something else?
Chris

Comment: OZK- Would you explain a little more? I see you've got some skill to add Hebrew to your post-kudos. Are you suggesting a user can change the appearance of a public web page to Hebrew provided the original page's encoding is UTF-8? However if my content is originally in English, its not "using" the extra characters. Without having any experience in this (>_<) I can imagine it useful if the original page is encoded using UTF=8 for Hebrew to English, why the other way around?

Comment: Hi, if your site doesn't support any dynamic content added by users (i.e. comments, posts, or even usernames) - then you may chose any encoding that fits your likings. but if you plan on having anything made by a user displayed (or even just stored in a DB for that matter) - i would strongly recommend UTF-8.

Answer (score 9):

IMHO it's always best to work with UTF-8.
Your preferences will not always reflect your users' preferences, which might happen to really like hebrew or Russian. שלום!

Comment: I tend to go the same way.  I just ensure that everything is UTF-8 all the way through, so I don't kick myself later.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is going to support only one language - it's better to use that language's native encoding. With two or more - consider UTF-8.